# _blank is affecting current tab as well as opening new tab. Why?

Tags: html

The website in question: http://www.chicagoswimschool.com/

When you click any of the Social Icons in the footer, it will open a new tab with the desired URL, but at the same time it will affect the current tab and redirect it to the desired URL. How can I make _blank ONLY open up a new tab and leave the previous tab unaffected?

The code for the links are pretty simple too

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/SwimWithCSS" target="_blank" title="Twitter icon"><span class="inner">twitter</span></a>
```

Comment: do you have an explicit example of that site doing this? Like a page on there with a text that is clearly a link?

Comment: There's no javascript that may be trigger ?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans he linked the site with the twitter button.

Comment: Mike, as I linked above you can click the website link in my post, scroll all the way down and click any of the Social Icons and it will do this.

Comment: That's done with JS. If you disable JS, there is no problem.

Comment: @Oriol this was also my guess I just test it work as expected.

Comment: looks like there's a click handler on the body, but it's hard to tell where it's actually added and what the function does. Definitely looks like a bug worth letting them know about though, in addition to this post on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done by the following code of /wp-content/themes/passage/js/ajax.min.js

```
$j(document).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
  if ($j(this).hasClass('bx-prev')) {
    return false
  }
  if ($j(this).hasClass('bx-next')) {
    return false
  }
  if ($j(this).parent().hasClass('load_more')) {
    return false
  }
  if ($j(this).parent().hasClass('comments_number')) {
    var t = $j(this).attr('href').split('#') [1];
    $j('html, body').scrollTop($j('#' + t).offset().top);
    return false
  }
  if ($j(this).closest('.no_animation').length === 0) {
    if (document.location.href.indexOf('?s=') >= 0) {
      return true
    }
    if ($j(this).attr('href').indexOf('wp-admin') >= 0) {
      return true
    }
    if ($j(this).attr('href').indexOf('wp-content') >= 0) {
      return true
    }
    document.location.href = $j(this).attr('href');
    if ($j(this).attr('href') !== 'http://#' && $j(this).attr('href') !== '#') {
      disableHashChange = true;
      var n = $j(this).attr('href');
      var r = n.indexOf(root);
      if (r === 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.stopPropagation();
        onLinkClicked($j(this))
      }
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }
})
```

You may try deleting that code, or specifically the line which changes `document.location.href`. But this approach could break other things.

A safer approach would be adding `no_animation` class to an ancestor of the icons, this way `$j(this).closest('.no_animation').length` won't be `0`.

Comment: Thanks! Am I supposed to just delete this part of the code?

Comment: @user3376981 Deleting it will solve this specific problem. But could break other things.

Comment: Very odd. I will try to see if deleting it can solve the problem without breaking anything, but if it does break important stuff I have no idea what to do